# Redrawing grid lines on a line chart (remove and redraw) in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I inherited a project that was using [d3.js](https://d3js.org/) and one of the charts was a line chart; I had to make a lot of changes to it, one being adding grid lines, I did this like so:

```
grid_wrap = plot.append('g').classed('grid-wrapper', true);

//......

chart = function() {

    //.....

    valueScale.domain([0, settings.value_scale_max]).range([plot_height, 0]);

    grid_wrap.append("g")
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("width", grid_width)
    .call(make_y_axis(valueScale)
        .tickSize(-grid_width)
        .tickFormat("")
    );

    //.....

}
```

Note the `chart` function above gets called on a redraw.

```
function make_y_axis(valueScale) {
    return d3.axisLeft()
   .scale(valueScale)
   .ticks(5);
}
```

Now, this draws the grid lines fine, however whenever the window is resized it uses a `resize` event trigger to redraw the graphs, however whilst everything else redraws correctly my grid lines instead get duplicated over and over ending up with several `.grid` elements.

I checked out how the other code is handling it and I understand it this way:

There are also these *threshold* elements on the graph and they are built this way:

```
thresholds = plot.append('g').classed('thresholds', true);

chart = function() {

    //.....

    valueScale.domain([0, settings.value_scale_max]).range([plot_height, 0]);

    thresholds = plot.select('.thresholds').selectAll('.threshold').data(chart.Thresholds);
```

Uses data to populate the *threshold* elements.

```
new_thresholds = thresholds.enter().append('g').attr('class', 'threshold');
```

Now, as I understand it, `thresholds` won't contain any elements on the first draw, but on redraws will contain the already existing elements.

`new_thresholds` will then work on this data and add needed *new* `.threshold` elements to match the amount needed in the dataset since we are using the `enter` function here.

```
new_thresholds.append('rect').classed('threshold-rect', true).attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0).attr('width', plot_width);
```

Adding elements to our newly created elements.

```
thresholds.exit().remove();
```

Then as I understand it this removes any extra elements that are too many compared to the dataset we provided?

```
    //.....

}
```

So I guess what I am asking is how can I achieve the same thing with the grid lines since it's not working on a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking it, all I had to do was add this:

```
grid_wrap.selectAll('.grid').remove();
```

above the below code...

```
grid_wrap.append("g")
.attr("class", "grid")
.attr("width", grid_width)
.call(make_y_axis(valueScale)
    .tickSize(-grid_width)
    .tickFormat("")
);
```

This makes sure any gridlines are removed before and hence when they get created it only ends up with the one being there.